# Altium Hotspot Snap of Pads in Footprint / PCB Library Designer

Tags: altium

I'm trying to create a footprint for a USB receptacle using the drawing of the recommended footprint for that part.

The problem I'm facing is that, as it is common with mechanical drawings, the distances between the edges of pads are specified instead of distances between pad centers. So I'd like the edge or corner of a pad to snap to the grid instead of the center of the pad. I have studied [this](http://wiki.altium.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=21660246) article, however hotspot or axis snap does not seem to work for simple pads. Is there another workaround?

Comment: Easiest solution is just calculate the center to center spacing from the mechanical drawing, and set your grid to make it easy to snap the pads to the correct locations.

Comment: Print it out on paper and get busy with a calculator. Easiest way. Verify spacings with the measurement tools when you're done.

Comment: I just place the pads down in the general location and manually set the x,y coordinates for every one. (using selections to set the x or y coordinate for rows or columns)

Comment: @ThePhoton this is what I ended up doing, however I wonder if there is a "Altium Way" for the future

Comment: Setting the grid to match the center to center spacing is the Altium way. Manually adjusting the X,Y's as Daniel suggests will also work.

Comment: I calculate the distances like ThePhoton suggested. Every time. It tends to be the easiest and quickest. Changing the snap grid in Altium so that pad edges jump to it, even if there is an "Altium Way" to do it, would have undesired side effects that you may not foresee. It's worth taking the extra 10 seconds to do the math on a calculator.